# Comparing integer variables for the largest within a range

Tags: java, int, max, min

I'm having trouble seeing why my code doesn't work for this problem I'm trying to work out.

The Question: 
Given 2 positive int values, return the larger value that is in the range 10..20 inclusive, or return 0 if neither is in that range.

My Code:

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  int max;

  if((a<10 || a>20) && (b<10 || b>20)) {
  max = 0;
  }

  if(Math.max(a,b) >= 10 && Math.max(a,b) <= 20) {
  max = Math.max(a,b);
  } else {
  max = Math.min(a,b);
  }

  return max;
}
```

Every number works except for when a = 9 and b = 21, which I just don't understand. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Step through your code with a debugger.

Comment: return 0 instead of setting max to 0

Comment: Thank you very much for the help everybody. I see where I went wrong now.

Answer (score 0):

Edited original answer because I oversaw some cases. 
The following should work to what you like

```
static int max1020(int a, int b) {
    int max = 0;
    if ((a < 10 || a > 20) && (b < 10 || b > 20)) {
        //If neither fall between 10 and 20, return immediately.
        return max;
    }
    if (Math.max(a, b) >= 10 && Math.max(a, b) <= 20) {
        //If both fall between 10 and 20, return the larger value.
        max = Math.max(a, b);
    } else if ((a >= 10) && (a <= 20)) {
        //If both didn't fall between 10 and 20, check if it was a.
        max = a;
    } else {
        //If a didn't fall between 10 and 20, then it must be b.
        max = b;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not returning 0 .. ever.. so.. 9 is less than 10.. and b greater than 20  so return 0.  I think you getting 9 because you are still executing the section when both numbers fall within the bounds.

public int max1020(int a, int b) {
          int max;

```
      if((a<10 || a>20) && (b<10 || b>20)) {
      **>> return 0;**
      }

      if(Math.max(a,b) >= 10 && Math.max(a,b) <= 20) {
      max = Math.max(a,b);
      } else {
      max = Math.min(a,b);
      }

      return max;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code says 
If a && b are not between 10 or 20 max = 0.

Then it moves on to calculating which is the max and which is the min no matter what the numbers are.

You should immediately return 0 if a&&b are not between 10 or 20.

eg.

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  int max;

if((a<10 || a>20) && (b<10 || b>20)) {
    return 0;
}

if(Math.max(a,b) >= 10 && Math.max(a,b) <= 20) {
    max = Math.max(a,b);
} else {
 max = Math.min(a,b);
}

return max;
}
```

Comment: Your else statement will never be reached.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
public int max1020(int a, int b) {
  int max = 0;
  if (10 <= a && a <= 20)
    max = a;
  if (10 <= b && b <= 20)
    max = Math.max(max, b);
  return max;
}
```